# Не работает отображение объектов из массива

Tags: javascript, html

Я написал скрипт, который должен выводить из массива данные, которые я указал, но там ошибка.
Не понимаю причину.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="products"></div>

    <script src="js/5json.js"></script>
    <script src="js/watch5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/root.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

5json.js(отрывок):

```
const CLASS5 = [
    {
        "query": "Царевна-Лягушка",
        "athor": "-",
        "pages": "3-4 листа А4",
        "age": "3+",
        "class": "5",
        "images": "json/1.jpg"
    },

    {
        "query": "Журавль и цапля",
        "athor": "-",
        "pages": "2-3 листа А4",
        "age": "3+",
        "class": "5",
        "images": "json/2.jpg"
    },

    {
        "query": "Солдатская шинель",
        "athor": "-",
        "pages": "4-6 листа А4",
        "age": "3+",
        "class": "5",
        "images": "json/3.jpg"
    },

    {
        "query": "Иван - крестьянский сын и чудо - юдо",
        "athor": "-",
        "pages": "3-5 листа А4",
        "age": "3+",
        "class": "5",
        "images": "json/4.jpg"
    },
```

root.js:

```
const ROOT_HEADER = document.getElementById("header")
const ROOT_PRODUCTS = document.getElementById("products")
```

watch5.js:

```
class Products {

    render() {
        let htmlCatalog = '';

        CLASS5.forEach(({ images, query }) => {
            
            htmlCatalog += `
                <li>
                    <img src="${images}">
                    <span>${query}</span>
                </li>
            `;
        });

        const html = `
            <ul>
                ${htmlCatalog}
            </ul>
        `;

        ROOT_PRODUCTS.innerHTML = html;
    }
}

const ProductsPage = new Products();
ProductsPage.render();
```

консоль ругается на стоку "ROOT_PRODUCTS.innerHTML = html;"

Comment: Какую конкретно выдает ошибку?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: ROOT_PRODUCTS is not defined
    at Products.render (watch5.js:22:9)
    at watch5.js:27:14

Comment: Подозреваю, что ругается на то, что ROOT_PRODUCTS не определено(undefined). Соберите все ваши js в один файл и должно заработать,

Comment: Работает, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

У вас root.js выполняется в конце, после watch5.js поэтому возникает `ReferenceError` (попытка обратиться к переменной или функции, которая не была определена). Т.е в момент выполнения watch5.js в памяти еще нет ваших переменных `ROOT_HEADER` и `ROOT_PRODUCTS`